# How to work with Redis from Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, macos, redis

I'm working on a `OS X` app which needs Redis support.

I've already tried `ObjCHiredis`, but it doesn't work for me (more about this issue here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.objective-c/amCX3yV7zQU).

There is extremely few information about this question in Google, so I came here.

One more thing is that I can connect to Redis server with `TCP socket (localhost:6379)` and send there some data (and receive it), it works with `telnet`, but I really can't find suitable library for Objective-C to make this.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly, with a little effort, you could use any of the C or C++ clients listed at http://redis.io/clients

The problem you're describing in your google groups post is caused by the ObjCHiredis framework not being properly embedded in your application's bundle.  You should [read up on embedding frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002258-106880-BAJJBIEF) -- it's not immediately straightforward, especially if you're new to the platform.

In terms of bootstrapping, you could also just get the source to ObjCHiredis and add it to your Xcode project and build it as part of your target.  But eventually, you'll want to figure out framework embedding.

Another option is to install the ObjCHiredis framework globally for your machine.  The [Framework Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Frameworks.html) should also tell you how to do that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll try this later a bit. I hope it will solve my problem.

Comment: So, I extracted all code from framework and add it to my project, fixed some bugs and it work now. I'll create my own wrapper for hiredis I think, for the new hiredis version. Anyway, thanks.